# Convert YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00 into excel numeric format in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I need to convert

```
2014-12-01T00:00:00 (YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00)
```

Into

```
41974 (numeric excel date format)
```

in XSLT 2.0. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With XPath/XSLT 2.0 you can substract an `xs:dateTime` from another and you have a duration, you can then extract the days from the duration:

```
days-from-duration(xs:dateTime('2014-12-01T00:00:00') - xs:dateTime('1899-12-30T00:00:00'))
```

This assumes the date 1899-12-30 is equivalent to the number `0`, which https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278460.aspx suggests saying "Negative whole numbers represent dates before 30 December 1899".

Comment: It did work in Altova XML Spy but in visual studio it throws below error. SEVERE:  17 Chained error: Caught COM Error in XSLTHandler::performTransform - HRESULT = [0x80004005], Message = [Unspecified error], Description = [Namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' does not contain any functions.  ] I ensured needed namespaces are in place.

Comment: Does the stylesheet have `version="2.0"`? And which XSLT processor do you use there within Visual Studio? Microsoft's own XSLT processor do not support XSLT 2.0, only 1.0.

Comment: I am using XSLT version ="2.0" but XSLT processor is 1.0 as you mentioned. Is there any way we can avoid in build functions for this issue?

Comment: The question was tagged as XSLT 2.0 and is answered, I am afraid with XSLT 1.0 you would need to write a lot of code trying to implement the date arithmetic or you would need to write a processor specific extension. So I think you would better ask a new question indicating exactly which XSLT 1.0 processor you use.